# How to put variable as argument in system()

Tags: c++, bash, c++11, gcc-pedantic

I am trying to include the `sleep 1` command in bash in my .cpp file 
While `system("sleep 1")` works fine, I would like to change `1` into a **const** **int** or **string**

```
const string t = "1";
string c = "sleep " + t;
system(c);
```

However, it seems like the `system(c)` is treated as a call to function as the following error occurs:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'system'
  system(c);
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Does calling it as "system(c.c_str());" help?

Comment: `system(c)` is a call to a function

Comment: @JosephLarson Yes it is solved, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `system` function takes a `const char*` pointer as its argument. However, there is no *implicit* conversion from a `std::string` object to a `const char*` (representing its contained string data) provided by the Standard Library. Instead, you can call the [`c_str()` member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) on that object, like so:

```cpp
system(c.c_str());
```

Answer (score 3):

`system(c.c_str())` or, equivalently (from C++11), `system(c.data())`